# eledmac and verse

Tags: verse, eledmac

I just want to come up with a rather general question regarding `eledmac` and typesetting verse. I am experimenting with that issue since while, but I wonder whether there is really a simple way to handle verse in `eledmac`. I want to typeset a critical edition of a text that is basically a mixture of prose and verse and I have serious problems to control the vertical space between the prose sections and the stanzas inbetween, or the space between a section of several verses. If I use the `quotation` environment, the space between the stanzas is too big or the line numbers and the text happen to be disarranged. Does anyone have experience with that? Other packages such as `ednotes` are far more tolerant in this regard, but have other general disadvantages wherefore I would like to stick to `eledmac`.

**Edit** ([Wang Junqi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/62420/wang-junqi))

This is to add MWE. I met almost the same problem with you. `eledmac` works pretty well in a file only consisting of proses. But in a mixture of verses and proses, line number is always disarranged and wrong. Sometimes as you said, the space between stanzas is too big or too small. I think it's a bug of `eledmac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\lineation{page}
\sidenotemargin{left}
\linenummargin{right}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
++++ contents
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

The result is as follows:

The line with number 30 should be line 31.

> [image: The line with number 30 should be line 31.]

In quote 45, the space between stanzas is too big or small.

> [image: The space between stanzas is too big or small]

It's obvious that the place of line number 15 is wrong.

> [image: It's obvious that the place of line number 30 is wrong.]

Comment: Stick with `eledmac`.  However, and I mean no offence by this, you have not really asked a question that can be answered (yet), only raised a vague complaint that is difficult to address without a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  Can you provide a real example of the problem(s) you would like fixed?  Changing vertical spacing between environments is normally trivial, but all the extra things `eledmac` either does or might need to worry about can sometimes make things tricky....

Comment: yes, a mwe should be welcome. Vertical spacing with eledmac is always complex, because of the way eledmac is cutting line to allow numbering and such thing.

Comment: is it possible to have a MWE?

Comment: we are still waiting more detial.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `\stanza` environment of `eledmac`.

I was able to do what you are trying to do by using the `\stanza` environment and by defining the `\startstanzahook`command to add space before the beginning of every verse, and the `\endstanzaextra` command to add space at the end.  These are custom commands that are automatically executed at the beginning and end of every `\stanza`, respectively.  I used XeLaTeX and `fontspec` for the diacritics.

```
\documentclass {article}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\setstanzaindents{0,1,1}

\newcommand*{\startstanzahook}{\vspace{9pt}}
\def\endstanzaextra{\vspace{9pt}}

\beginnumbering
\autopar

\stanza 
śāstrasyāsya praṇetāram abhyarhya sugatātmajam |&
vaktāraṃ cāsmadādibhyo yatiṣye 'arthavivecane ||\&

tatrāditaḥ śāstraśarīraṃ vyavasthāpyate

\stanza
lakṣaṇaṃ hyāvṛtistattvaṃ pratipakṣasya bhāvanā |&
tatrāvasthā phalaprāptir yānānuttaryam eva ca ||1||\&

\noindent ityete saptārthā hyasmin śāstra upadiśyante | yaduta lakṣaṇam āvaraṇaṃ tattvaṃ pratipakṣasya bhāvanā tasyāmeva ca pratipakṣabhāvanāyām avasthāḥ phalaprāptiḥ yānānuttaryañ ca saptamo 'rthaḥ ||1||

tatra lakṣaṇam ārabhyāha---

\stanza
abhūtaparikalpo 'sti dvayaṃ tatra na vidyate&
sūnyatā vidyate tvatra tasyāmapi sa vidyate ||2||\&

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: instead of adding `\x` you can just define `\endstanzaextra`. It's nice to you to have understood the question.

Comment: Ah!  Yes, this is a better solution.

Comment: My answer has been updated accordingly.

Comment: Although, @Maïeul, I notice that when I try to define `\startstanzahook` and `\endstanzaextra` as above in a document made with two columns using `eledpar`, they do not take effect.  Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: yes I know. It the same problem with hook from eledmac to eledpar : the hooks is called when the pstart is called, not when the \Columns or \Pages is called. Open an issue on github.